# How should i fix required a bean of type that could not be found?

Tags: java, spring

I keep on getting an error: `"required a bean that could not be found."`
And i really can't figure out why anymore.

I saw that many had the same issue as me before but none of the given answers work for me. Tried rearranging packages, adding `@ComponentScan` to the application but nothing helped.

Part of my controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class JavarskiKontroler {

@Autowired
private JavarService javarService;

@RequestMapping("/javari")
public List<Javar> getAllJavars() {
    return javarService.getAllJavars();
}

@PostMapping("/javar")
public Javar createJavar(@Valid @RequestBody Javar note) {
    return javarService.createJavara(note);
}
```

Part of my service implementation (JavarService):

```
@Service
public class JavarService {


@Autowired
private Javarer javarica;

public List<Javar> getAllJavars() {

    return javarica.findAll();
}

public Javar createJavara(Javar note) {

    return javarica.save(note);
}
```

My service(Javarer):

```
@Repository
public interface Javarer extends JpaRepository<Javar, Integer> {
}
```

And the error that I keep on getting:

**Description:**

```
 Field javarService in controller.JavarskiKontroler required a bean of type 'serviceImpl.JavarService' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
- 
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

 Action:

 Consider defining a bean of type 'serviceImpl.JavarService' in your configuration.
```

[image: project structure:]

It would be great if someone could at least point me to where I should look for the solution next, thanks anyway.

Comment: can you update project structure, packages

Comment: Here you go, hope it helps.

Comment: your packages are unstructured, use `@ComponentScan`

Comment: What is the full stacktrace? What is the exception cause? It might be the service cannot be injected because there wasanother exception building its dependencies.

Comment: @Deadpool works now somehow, funny part is that i tried the same method before and it didn't, guess it was a typo or something. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your packages are unstructured, use `@CompnentScan` including packages names on `Main` class

```
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"controller", "domain", "exception", "service" })
```